# After pip install guniorn, terminal shows that command not found: gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn

I try to use flask and gunicorn to build a web service.

After using `pip install gunicorn`, and installed scuccessfully.

But when I run `gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf app:app`

There is `zsh: command not found: gunicorn`

Environment:

- MacOS

I want to know how to fix this, or there is other way to run gunicorn? like a python file?

Comment: You probably installed gunicorn in the wrong Python environment. You can have a look at the installed packages via `pip freeze`.

Comment: I do have python2.7 and python3 in my sys, and pip3 list has had `gunicorn==20.1.0`.   @J.G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to always use a virtual environment to isolate project specific packages.

To create a virtual environment use `python3.8 -m venv venv`

Diving to your issue on gunicorn

1. Make sure you have installed gunicorn to project virtual environment.
2. Active the environment with `source venv/bin/active`
3. run gunicorn as usual

If gunicorn is not working as usual there is other way you can start by directly accessing the gunicorn file where it is installed.

```
/home/ubuntu/Projects/myproject/venv/bin/gunicorn -c "config/gunicorn.py" "main:deliver_app(run_type='prod')"
```